# How can we check for 2 timestamp for same day?

Tags: javascript, angular, date

How can we check 2 timestamps for same day? This is my response from db.
I have compare the entire response for the same day.
 If the 2 created dates(same day) are equal, I have to merge the events.

```
[{    createdAt: Date,
    duration: number,   
    sessionId: string,
    events:[]   
},
{    createdAt: Date,
    duration: number,   
    sessionId: string  ,
    events:[]    
},
{    createdAt: Date,
    duration: number,   
    sessionId: string  ,
    events:[]    
},
{    createdAt: Date,
    duration: number,   
    sessionId: string ,
    events:[]     
}]
```

I have no idea how to do this. I tried with new Date().getDate() to compare the dates.

Comment: @Muowee—saying "use Moment.js" for questions about dates is as useful as saying "use jQuery" for every question about the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

You could loop over the dates and apply Angulars Date Pipe to them. Formatting them all in the same way for example "longDate" and then use == to check if they are the same date.

https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe - here is a link to the date pipe, you can use the formatDate() method.

Alternatively you could use moment library but this is fairly large for something that can be achieved with something you already have in your project.

Answer (score 0):

```
if( Date1.getDate() == Date2.getDate() 
    && Date1.getMonth() == Date2.getMonth() 
    && Date1.getYear() == Date2.getYear()){
     //They are on the same day
 } else {
    // Not on the same day
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Presuming you have Date objects, you can compare the result of *toDateString* for local dates, or the first 10 characters of *toISOString* for UTC dates.

E.g.

```js
function sameLocalDate(d0, d1) {
  return d0.toDateString() == d1.toDateString();
}

function sameUTCDate(d0, d1) {
  return d0.toISOString().substr(0, 10) == d1.toISOString().substr(0, 10);
}

let d0 = new Date()
let d1 = new Date();
d1.setHours(d1.getHours() + 10);

console.log(
  'd0 local: '   + d0.toString() +
  '\nd1 local: ' + d1.toString() +
  '\nSame local date? ' + sameLocalDate(d0, d1) +
  '\nd0 UTC: ' + d0.toISOString() +
  '\nd1 UTC: ' + d1.toISOString() +
  '\nSame UTC date? ' + sameUTCDate(d0, d1)
);
```